# Angular - How to fire change events on loaded partial?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Presently, I am trying to load a select box (a really big one) via an html partial. The loading I can do, however getting Angular to fire a change event when the user interacts with the partial has been more complicated. Likewise, I am having a tough time getting the select box to be set to a default value. What (all) am I doing wrong here? Do you know any resources that cover how to work with partials to do this sort of thing?

The code I am working with looks like so:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

      $scope.updateData = function() {
        console.log('Updating data');
      };

      // Initial run to fetch weather data
      $scope.updateData();
    }])


    .directive('tzSelect', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log(element);
          

        },

        templateUrl: 'partials/tzselect.html'
      };
    });

} (window.angular));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Select by partial</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <div class="my-app" ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="AppController">

        <div class="top-row clearfix">
          <div class="section form-container">
            <h2>Weather settings</h2>
            <form name="my-form">
              <div class="squeeze">
                <label for="city">City, State</label>
                <input 
                  type="text" 
                  ng-model="city"> <!-- ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}" -->
                <br>
                <tz-select></tz-select>
                <button ng-click="updateData()" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- The partial loaded from file -->
<div>
<label for="tzselect">Timezone</label>
<select name="tzselect" ng-model="tzSelect" ng-init="tzSelect = options[0]" ng-change="tzChange()"> <!-- ng-change="tzChange()"  ng-transclude> -->
  <option timeZoneId="1" gmtAdjustment="GMT-12:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-12" selected="selected">(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West</option>
  <option timeZoneId="2" gmtAdjustment="GMT-11:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-11">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
  <option timeZoneId="3" gmtAdjustment="GMT-10:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-10">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
  <option timeZoneId="4" gmtAdjustment="GMT-09:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-9">(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>
  <option timeZoneId="5" gmtAdjustment="GMT-08:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-8">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)</option>
</select>
</div>
```

tz-select is brought in via the directive. This code is a simplification of code that I am working with to create a weather app that started off as a controller only based tutorial. I hope you can help!

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have tried adding the tzChange handler to the controller but that didnt get me anywhere... So I didn't include it here.

Comment: Well, I re-added a change event in my scope and lo and behold it worked!

I added the following in the controller:

$scope.tzChange = function() {
    console.log('Firing change');
};

Comment: And I got it working in the full (weatherApp) version - turns out I was referring to the event as txChange() in the html (typo). Now I just need to figure out how to get the default option to show up on the loaded select box.